# Can an energy saving powerboard damage your computer?

Tags: cpu, power-supply, overheating

Two months ago, I bought a [Jackson Master/Slave Green Energy Saving Powerboard](http://www.ji.com.au/products/PT9778/).  I plugged my high-end gaming desktop computer into the master port, and the screen, speakers, etc. into the slave ports.  This appeared to be working correctly.  When the computer went to sleep, all peripherals turned off automatically.  When the computer woke, the peripherals turned on again.

I recently noticed that when the computer was sleeping, the speakers and screen would turn on intermittently just for a couple of seconds.  I thought the computer might be drawing an additional current momentarily for some reason.

Last night, my computer spontaneously turned off after 10 minutes.  Then on again, then off again, then repeat.  I removed the Green Powerboard and replaced it with a regular one.  I opened the computer and dusted it and the heat sinks thoroughly.  Nothing felt hot.  I started it again.  After being on for a couple of minutes, the computer repeated its flailing.

I suspect either an overheating CPU or GPU or a faulty power supply is the issue due to the symptoms.  I can't install a CPU Temperature monitor quickly enough to measure the temperature.  Maybe the power supply was damaged by the Green Powerboard, or it could just be coincidental timing given it's three years old.

I want help narrow down the cause to prevent unnecessary expense and effort.  **Is there any evidence that Green Powerboards can damage or wear out computer equipment?**  **Is a three-year lifespan for a power supply reasonable or too short?**  If I replace my power supply, am I going to burn it out again using the Green Powerboard?

Comment: The method used should in no way effect the Main item on the power strip, the other items will be little differet than being unplugged (way more times). I see little reason to suspect this particular method, as being a big problem, or causing your problem. There are other (not this one) power savings methods that are not good for the main computer at all. Just speculation until I Own one and can test more things about it. If it is acting flakey and not knowing when the main item is off or not, I would stop using it.

Comment: This is most likely coincidence.  Perhaps the thermal paste isn't fully contacting the heatsink or the cpu fan is not spinning.  Or it could well be PSU.  You should have a temperature monitor in the bios too - there isn't much load when running the bios, but it might give you a clue as to where the cut off is happening.  Also, if it happens in the bios screen - it makes the PSU a more likely culprit.

Comment: I think you're on to something, @Paul.  Just looking at the BIOS, the CPU temperature rises above 90°C within 90 seconds.  I think you've diagnosed my problem, but I'd still be interested in any information regarding Green Powerboards.  The intermittent powering of the slave peripherals still has me concerned.

Comment: Wow, that is paste or the fan I'd say - does it spin?

Comment: @Hand-E-Food The computer is not "off" when it is in the off state, nics, keyboards, and ps2 ports , and the ability to turn-on can be held up by  a 5V standby power line. until the switch on the back of the power supply is off, there is "some power" used. The ammount used Can be adjusted for some nics. I suspect that the green device kicks on when the use of this 5V standby power goes up.  I would check the Nics own driver properties and tabs. Anything that you changed too might be using tiny bits more power.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely that a 3 year old computer would now start having thermal issues related to improperly or insufficiently supplied thermal paste on the CPU, as those would have manifested themselves very quickly, or a failing GPU, as it would've manifested itself in other ways rather than shutting down your computer immediately. It sounds a lot more like a power supply issue. You might be able to alleviate the problem temporarily, and narrow down the issue, by lowering the strain on the PSU by unplugging the GPU via the PCI-E cables and using the on-board video (provided you have one). If it still has an issue, it's definitely the power supply. I realize you're unplugging two variable components at the same time, but this is with the speculation that the PSU is the issue.

As @Paul said, sitting in the bios is a good way to look at thermals quickly and provides a very low-power state for the computer.